# Every object is added in the same collection

Tags: collections

I am trying to create a person in Blender. I have the collection Human, with a cube which was the initial cube that i created to start. After that I created a few more and make the parts of the arms and legs etc. But everything is being added in the same cube. Now in Object mode I cannot select only one leg for example. Because I want to duplicate and rotate so I can make the left leg just as the right one. So how can I select the leg for example and make in a different collection?

[image]

Comment: maybe you meant that all the pieces are created within the same object? In that case, in Edit mode, put your mouse on one of the pieces, press L, press P to separate, switch back to Object mode, the piece is now its own object. You can have several meshes within one object.

Comment: As moonboots says you can separate them into different objects, but the best way is to add them in Object mode in the first place! Lots of beginners add objects when in Edit mode and wonder why they can't move them individually as you've found.

Comment: Alright guys, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things here: collections and objects.

A collection is just an organizational tool. Similar to a group, a folder. It's just meant to tidy up your scene and setup some visibility / selectability option on a group of objects.

An object is a physical container in your 3D scene, that contains some form of data. An object has a position/rotation/scale coordinates in the 3D space, has different display and render options, and most importantly. The data it contains can be text, mesh, curves and whatnot.

When you are in object mode, you manipulate the objects, the container. Not their content. If you add a cube while in Object mode, it creates a new object with a mesh cube inside.
But when you are in edit mode, you are editing the selected object's content. If you add a cube, it simply adds a mesh cube inside the current object. So you are not creating new objects, you are actually adding mesh inside the current object.

And that is the source of your issue here I guess. You were in edit mode when you added all your meshes, thinking you were adding new objects.

To turn your meshes back to objects, there is the Separate menu in edit mode, called with <kbd>P</kbd>. It has several options, the two interesting for you will probably be "selected" to separate a selection into another object, and "by lose part" which will separate every individual mesh into a different object.
If you just want to separate each individual mesh into individual objects, then the "by lose part" is the best option as it will do exactly that in one click. If you want to chose precisely the mesh parts to separate, then select your meshes manually. And you might want to use <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering a mesh part so select it entirely.